# Xcode 6.3 Storyboard Autolayout Constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-autolayout

This is my storyboard:

[image: Storybaord]

This is the iPad Simulator:

[image: iPad Simulator]

For the constraints I go to the bottom right and click on the button that has a triangle with two extruding bars (it sort of looks like a star wars fighter with a triangle as the cockpit).  I scroll down to the section that says all view in view controller I click on clear constraints.  Then I go back to the same button but this time I click add missing constraints.

Why is this happening?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding missing constraints doesn't mean "add the constraint I think will look better in my project". Xcode adds some constraints to keep everything in place, but this may (or may not) be what you want.

To paint a control in place without ambiguity your need at least 4 constraint, two on each axe (two for X, two for Y). I recommend to clear all constraints, and start control by control, adding constraints.

Some tips:

- you can set the constraints, then move a control, ask Xcode to refresh the constraints to the new position with the *update Constraints* option. *update frames* option do the opposite: given a set of constraints, repaints your control in the right position.

[image: update frames]

- Use the Assistant editor to split your Xcode view, so you can select *Preview* and have while designing your Storyboard and see how it looks. You can add different devices to see how it fits (little + button at the bottom)

[image: Preview]

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot now it looks how I want it to look

Comment: When I clicked on the little '+' button, I couldn't see the iPad option.I could see iPhone 3.5,4,4.7,5.5 inch screens,but not iPad. I just want to see how my constraints work on iPad with these iPhone screens.

Comment: Have you added the iPad to your deployment info? Go to Your Project > Your Target > General tab. Here, look at Deployment Info section. In Devices, select Universal, so you can see iPad Storyboards and also preview iPad screens

Comment: Yea. It is UNIVERSAL.